# ssh, shutdown problem, pi 3B+

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, shutdown, reboot

I could not find answer to my question reading the forum, Im having unusual problem with my new pi 3b+. I'm able to connect my Pi with ethernet cable, and I can ssh to it. So no problem with connecting to pi, but when I type `sudo reboot`, or `sudo shutdown -h now`, my ssh connection immediately breaks with an error: `Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection`. It happens the second I type the command. Im guessing this is not correct, I should get message that Pi is shutting down right?

Comment: No that is what should happen. The SSH service needs to be terminated before a shutdown or reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `now` to `shutdown` or call for `reboot`, then the command take immediate effect. Among other things it stops the `ssh` services and you can / will get cold-dropped like that.  If you want to get a warning, then you need to specify a future time for the command to execute.

Comment: Oh, thank you. After I asked the question I thought maybe that's actually okay. Thank you for clearing my doubts.